# Can questions be listed by number of times viewed?

Tags: support, feature-request

Is there any way to list questions ordered by the number of views, from most to least?

If not, is this something that could be added?

I think it would be interesting and useful to see which questions have drawn the most visitors and hits. These would be questions many people are asking via search engines, and finding pages here in response to their searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to make the above query by El'endia a little more spicy... lists along with score and no of favorites...

[Most Views](https://data.stackexchange.com/christianity/query/294993/most-views)

You can change the number of questions in the list by simply editing it in the query to ur desired no.

:)

Comment: +1 for improving it! :)

Comment: @El'endia Starman & servantofWiser: Thanks for the query, and the query on steroids. Fascinating! And it shows just how tough it is to keep questions (and answers) within the guidelines and purpose of this site. Many of people's most aching questions just can't be answered properly here. But it's still a highly useful site.

Comment: It would be great if this capability could be added to the main site!

Comment: request this to the mods in the Upper Room of [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room) or raise a new meta question about this. @LeeWoofenden

Answer (score 5):

I created a quick Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) query that returns the top 500 questions with respect to the number of views.

[Sort Questions by Views](https://data.stackexchange.com/christianity/query/294849/sort-questions-by-views)

Far and away the top two questions, both of which have about twice as many views as the third place contender, are [Clarification of what sexual immorality is? [closed]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11299) and [What are the different names of God in the Bible and what do they mean? [closed]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/695).

Comment: Both top questions are off topic too sadly!